# create angular component tooltip programmatically

Tags: javascript, angular

I should show a tooltip when I hover an svg element.

I would like that the tooltip is an angular component for easier UI creating.

the constraint is that the svg element is created programmatically so I don't know how to create the template referencer for dynamic component rendering.

My question is how can I build an angular component as a tooltip of a dynamic svg element ?

Here's a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vgjjl-dyap5s?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts) on stackblitz. I wrote the code of the dynamic component. now I should render it dynamically when hovering the circle.

```
@ViewChild('cont', { static:true,read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
@ViewChild('svg', { static: true }) svg: ElementRef

ngAfterViewInit() {
  let circle= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','circle')
  circle.setAttribute('r','40');
  circle.setAttribute('cx','50');
  circle.setAttribute('cy','50');
  //let cont= document.createAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','#cont')
  //circle.setAttribute('#cont','test')
  this.svg.nativeElement.appendChild(circle)
  this.entry.clear();
  const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);
  const componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it either through creating a custom component or by using a tooltip directly on the SVG. Either way, you will want to watch the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events of either the SVG or the circle element directly by using RxJS.

You can see an example of this in this forked stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vgjjl-7qmneg?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.ts

Comment: ow, the power of rxjs .. but this method have it's limits: if svg contain other elements the tooltip will not target the concerned circle https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vgjjl-vtvjqu?file=app/tooltip-overview-example.ts

Comment: That is true, so you can target the svg directly. If you do that though, you will get the tooltip on the entire svg; not just your one element. Since your question was about targeting the SVG circle, I thought that would be best. If you want to see this, change **circle** in the **fromEvent** methods to **this.svg.nativeElement**. It was what I did first. Also, it still works on the targeted circle except that your second circle overlaps the first one so there is a small area that it won't work.